# Perfect field of characteristic $p>0$ which is not an algebraic extension of the prime field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

True/False

> If $K$ is a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$, then is $K$ algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

My guess is no and I try to find a counterexample for this. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: @user:I am sorry, I will take note of that in the future.

Comment: I know it's easy to say bla-bla, but you can show that you really mean that by turning back to the questions and accept/upvote the good answers you've got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: algebraically closed fields are perfect.

Comment: Aren't both $K$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ perfect?I am confused where is the contradiction?

Comment: @Jane The algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p(X)$ is perfect and not an algebraic extension of $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @Jane: how many algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p$ (up to isomorphism) can you name? Surely not just the algebraic closure of ${\bf F}_p$?

Answer (score 5):

Take $K=\mathbb F_p(X,X^{1/p},\dots,X^{1/p^n},\dots)$.